# Maybe a trivial problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone give me some suggestion about an elementary method (that is, without using advanced theorems in complex analysis. I only know that to integrate a complex-valued function, we do it with respect to its real part and imaginary part respectively. I did not learn complex analysis before...) to show that the following integration is equal to $0$? Many thanks!

$$\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{1+x^2}\cdot \bigg(\frac{i-x}{i+x}\bigg)^n\,\mathrm{d} x$$
where $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I first separate the real part and imaginary part of the integrand explicitly, and then there comes a difficulty about dealing with the expression

Comment: The difficulty is from the binomial expansion $(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}+i\,\frac{2x}{1+x^2})^n$.

Comment: Are you sure the result you claim is correct?

Comment: (@dfeuer Precisely.)

Comment: @dfeuer Wolfram alpha seems to tell me it is $\dfrac{\sin(n\pi)}{n}$, which is $0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2F%281+%2B+x%5E2%29+%28%28I+-+x%29%2F%28I+%2B+x%29%29%5En%2C+%7Bx%2C+-Infinity%2C+Infinity%7D%5D

Comment: @Macavity, yes, you're right. I entered the formula incorrectly the first time. Whoops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crazy thing is this (which I got after seeing WA results):

\begin{align*}
\frac d {dx}\left(\frac{i-x}{i+x}\right)^n&=n\left(\frac{i-x}{i+x}\right)^{n-1}\frac{-(i+x)-(i-x)}{(i+x)^2}\\
&=n\left(\frac{i-x}{i+x}\right)^{n-1}\frac{-2i}{(i+x)^2}\\
&=\left(\frac{i-x}{i+x}\right)^n\frac{-2in}{(i+x)(i-x)}\\
&=\left(\frac{i-x}{i+x}\right)^n\frac{2in}{1+x^2}
\end{align*}

So
$$\int \left(\frac{i-x}{i+x}\right)^n\frac{2in}{1+x^2}\,dx=\left(\frac{i-x}{i+x}\right)^n+C_0,$$
so
$$\int \frac 1 {x^2+1}\left(\frac{i-x}{i+x}\right)^n\,dx=\frac1{2in}\left(\frac{i-x}{i+x}\right)^n+C.$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{i-x}{i+x}
&=\frac{i^2-2ix+x^2}{i^2-x^2}\\
&=\frac{x^2-1-2ix}{-1-x^2}.
\end{align*}
As $x\to\pm\infty$, the real part of this ratio approaches $-1$ while the imaginary part approaches $0$. This same behavior holds, then, for all positive integer powers of the ratio, so the definite integral over the reals is $0$ as you claimed.

**Note:** a somewhat more interesting sort of odd-even pattern appears if you enter the integral incorrectly, taking it from $0$ to $\infty$ instead of $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Even tedious, it is understandable according to my knowledge.